# Проблемы с библиотекой pyCraft

Tags: python, pycraft

Установил библиотеку через pip, но я ловлю ошибку которую опишу ниже. Вот код:

```
from pycraft import MinecraftClient

# Создание экземпляра клиента
client = MinecraftClient()

# Подключение к серверу Minecraft
client.connect("IP_адрес_сервера", порт)

# Вход игрока на сервер с указанным ником
client.login("ник_игрока")

# Ожидание подключения и обработка событий
while True:
    event = client.events.poll()
    # Обработка событий, например, получение сообщений от других игроков
    if isinstance(event, ChatReceivedEvent):
        print(f"Получено сообщение: {event.message}")

    # Дополнительный код для взаимодействия с сервером Minecraft

# Отключение от сервера
client.disconnect()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'MinecraftClient' from 'pycraft' (/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycraft/__init__.py)

[Program finished]
```

Ошибка явно не в "неверной установке", так как если я просто сделаю `import pycraft`, то ошибки не будет

Comment: ImportError не значит неверную установку. Это значит, что вы или не то, или не оттуда импортируете. Проверьте наличие MinecraftClient в библиотеке pycraft.

Comment: Ну короче как я понимаю, не стоит просить бота сгенеровать код с малоизвестными библиотеками. Я просто написал клиент на с++

Comment: Да, бота просить не стоит. Писать надо из своей головы. А если что-то не получается, стараться разобраться. Ошибки из ничего не берутся.